# alternative to "high depth", "large depth"

Tags: adjectives

After having used "high depth" in a report, I consider it now almost as an oxymoron. But, is "large depth" better English? What would be an alternative adjective? (I'm not looking for the abyss as I am writing a technical report.)

Comment: Bad (because not used by normal native speakers): *High depth, large depth*. Good: *Great depth,* [for very great depths] *profound depth.*

Comment: If you’re talking about oceans, _vast depth_ also works, though Erik’s _great depth_ is by far the most common.

Comment: The fact is that mostly we measure up, and therefore when we measure down it hasta be because we're measuring something **really** big, like an ocean, that keeps us at the top. Normally in a lab graduates are graduated from the bottom up.

Answer (score 3):

As already noted in the comments, the usual collocation with depth is *great.*

[image]

It is also possible to use ngrams to check usual collocations with the "*_ADJ depth*" search, providing the top ten from their corpus.

[image]